# Dynamo db read/write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, read-write

Scenario:

If I read/ write an item of 10Bytes, Dynamo DB rounds up the throughput to 4Kb for read and 1Kb for write. If my entire DB consists of items which are 10-50 Bytes and I expect around 10 read/write operations per second, it becomes very inefficient.

Question:

Is there a way to overcome this and use the entire potential of every throughput

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rules for "Capacity Unit Consumption for Reads":

> GetItem—reads a single item from a table. To determine the number of
>   capacity units GetItem will consume, take the item size and round it
>   up to the next 4 KB boundary. If you specified a strongly consistent
>   read, this is the number of capacity units required. For an eventually
>   consistent read (the default), take this number and divide it by two.
>
> For example, if you read an item that is 3.5 KB, DynamoDB rounds the
>   item size to 4 KB. If you read an item of 10 KB, DynamoDB rounds the
>   item size to 12 KB.

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html

So maybe you could switch to *eventually consistent read*.

For `PutItem` and `UpdateItem`:

> For PutItem, UpdateItem, and DeleteItem operations, DynamoDB rounds
>   the item size up to the next 1 KB. For example, if you put or delete
>   an item of 1.6 KB, DynamoDB rounds the item size up to 2 KB.

Comment: Yes, that's possible but what if I read/write 10 items at different times? I will not b able to use a batch operation in that scenario

Comment: Yeah, i have updated my answer. I  think it's only possible by using eventually consistent read.